# I am trying to make a "top down" tile based game. I can't figure out how to initially make the tilemap to place the images on

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Python and Pygame and i was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to create the tile map to place the tile "sprites" on for my game. I have looked it up a bit and I can't find anything. I have some code to maybe give you an idea of where I'm going with this game(it doesn't work of course). Could anyone help?

```
    import pygame, sys, random
    from pygame.locals import *

    # constants representing colors
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREY = (128, 128, 128)

    #constants representing the different resources
    LAVA = 0
    STONE = 1

    # a dictionary linking the resources to textures
    colors =  {
                LAVA : RED,
                STONE : GREY,
                }

    # a list representing our tilemap
    tilemap = [
                [LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, STONE, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA],
                [LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA, LAVA],

    ]

    # useful game dimensions
    TILESIZE = 20
    MAPWIDTH = 30
    MAPHIGHT = 30

    # a list of resources
    resources = [LAVA, STONE]
    # use list comprehension to create our tilemap
    tilemap = [[LAVA for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHIGHT)]

    # set up the display
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHIGHT*TILESIZE))

    while True:
        # get all the user events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # if the user wants to quit
            if event.type == QUIT:
                # end the game and close the window
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # loop through each row
        for row in range(MAPHIGHT):
            # loop through each column
            for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
                # draw the resource at that position in the tilemap, using the correct color
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, colors[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE, row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

        # update the display
        pygame.display.update()
```

I expected there to be a grid, 30x30 tiles, with a border of 2 Orange "lava" tiles, along all sides, and a center of grey "stone" tiles in the center. But instead I just get a full screen of red :(.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `tilemap` with this line a few lines after you initialize it:

```
tilemap = [[LAVA for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHIGHT)]
```